# Overflow-y está deixando um espaço em branco na largura da tabela

Tags: html, css

Olá.

Estou tentando fazer com que a minha tabela possua um scroll, da seguinte forma:

```
<table ng-if="vm.model.id" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer" style="width: 100%; height: 350px; overflow-y: auto; display: block">
```

Porém, está sempre sobrando um espaço em branco grande do lado direito, antes do scroll.

Alguém sabe algo que eu possa tentar para não ter este problema mais?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O que ocorre é que você aplicou o display block a uma tabela, recomendo que você envolva a tabela em uma div e aplique o overflow na mesma.